# Flash ad network for non-games

Tags: flash, ads

I'm looking for a flash ad network which serves preloader ads for my flash application, just like [MochiAds](http://www.mochiads.com), *except* that my flash apps are, strictly speaking, not games, and therefore are not eligible for sign-up at MochiAds.  Is there a similar network which offers me such a service?

Comment: My question is about using ads in a program which I write (<cynical>a process called, I beleive, programming</cynical>), so it is, literally, related to programming. So I think the not-programming-related tag is misleading, but what the heck... Not going to start a revert war on that.

Answer (score 0):

The NewGrounds API is used for anything posted in their Portal, be it apps, games or cartoons.